# What is the big O of the following Binary Search Tree method

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, space-complexity

I know this might be trivial but i just want to make sure. I believe it's runtime will be at most O(n). My reasoning is that every node will return a height value once throughout this recursive method. Or in other words we will visit every node in the tree once.

```
    def height(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            return 0
        else:
            left_max = self._left.height()
            right_max = self._right.height()
            return max(left_max, right_max) + 1
```

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/95785

Answer (score 0):

- You are performing DFS traversal on tree all nodes will be visited only one time.
- So obviously it will take time of O(N) only.